# update one row in the SQL database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans

I am creating a project in netbeans. I have connected it to my database. I can insert data without any problem. When updating a single appointment, every id's appointments will change to whatever the user has input. Please help me. Kindly check my code if there are errors or wrong conditions. I think I'm  having problems with the proper condition. This is my code below:

```
private void jsaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    String newname = jnewpat.getText();
    String newage = jnage.getText();
    String newgen = jngen.getText();
    String renew = jnapp.getText();

    if (newname.equals("") || newage.equals("") || newgen.equals("") || renew.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please complete all the fields!");
        jnewpat.setText("");
        jnage.setText("");
        jngen.setText("");
        jnapp.setText("");
    }
    else
    {
        String query = "UPDATE tblcare SET appointment = ? WHERE id = ?";
       try {

            try (PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement(query)) {

            update.setString(1, jnapp.getText());
                int id = 0;
            update.setInt(2, id);
            update.executeUpdate();
```

}

```
            jnewpat.setText("");
            jnage.setText("");
            jngen.setText("");
            jnapp.setText("");
            Main back = new Main();
            back.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }

        catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
   }


    }

}
```

Comment: So, what can we do now ? I dont see any question in the question.

Comment: 1) "' WHERE id = id" should use some id variable 2) use prepared statement instead of constructing SQL by hand

Comment: You didn't ask a question, you don't tell us your problem, you don't tell us what you would like.

Comment: What is the proper condition for UPDATE tblcare SET appointment= WHERE? I think I'm having a problem with that

Comment: Your problem is WHERE Id = Id. You are comparing the Id column in tblcare with itself. Which means it will always be true, thus you update every record in the table. You need to pass the actual database id value for that record you want to update to your WHERE clause if you want to update a single record. It should be more like WHERE Id = ? and you pass a parameter containing the single Id value for the record you want to update.

Comment: @JacobH I just noticed it earlier. I thought it was okay but all saved data has changed its appointment to what appointment another user has input.

Comment: Yes, you are updating all columns where the Id in the table matches itself, which will always be every record in the table. It's almost the equivalent of saying "WHERE 1=1" (always true). You need to pass an Id in your code. If you don't know the Id you need to query it first. Are you inserting these records earlier in your code? If so, you can return the Id to a variable then pass it to this update.

Comment: Do you have SSMS installed? This might make more sense if you are testing your SQL scripts so you can see the results.

Comment: int id = 0;
update.setInt(2, id); So now you'll always update item with id 0?